# WPF ListBox Scroll Problems

Tags: c#, wpf

What should I do if I want to see the most recent input in the list box?
Currently, I have to scroll down to see the last Input.
How do I implement automatically scroll down?

```
 <ListBox x:Name="IbInfo"
           DockPanel.Dock="Top"
           Background="#FF162127"
           Foreground="White" 
           BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
          Margin="20,0,180.0,11"/>
```

[image]

Comment: IbInfo.selectedindex = IbInfo.Items.count

Comment: I tried the solution you told me, but the error line came out.

Comment: Basically like this: ` .... = IbInfo.Items.count-1;` .  But it depends on how and when you make this assignment. Also this code Selects an element, but it won't scroll the Area of ​​visibility to that element.

Comment: are you sure that scrolling down makes more sense than to reverse the list?

Comment: To scroll the Area of visibility, call the ScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoend?view=windowsdesktop-7.0
To do this, try calling `IbInfo.ScrollIntoView(IbInfo.SelectedItem)` after setting the selected item.